# What does KEY mean in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does this line mean?

> `KEY FK_CodigoCliente_idx (CodigoCliente),`

```
CREATE TABLE tbvenda (
  Codigo int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CodigoCliente int(11) NOT NULL,
  DataVenda date NOT NULL,
  ValorTotal decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  Situacao int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Codigo),
  KEY FK_CodigoCliente_idx (CodigoCliente),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CodigoCliente FOREIGN KEY (CodigoCliente) REFERENCES tbcliente (Codigo)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KEY` is a keyword in MySQL that essentially means "build an index on these columns".  It is synonymous with `INDEX` (although more common, and a handy way to declare indexes directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

This is actually explained pretty well in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) (although buried on the `CREATE TABLE` page):

> KEY | INDEX
>
> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can
>   also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This
>   was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but it's necessary I use it?

Comment: @WSS . . . Not at all.  You wouldn't use it if you didn't want an index (for instance).  You can always add indexes later (and that is often a good idea).  It is generally redundant if the same column/columns are expressed as a `primary key` or `unique` constraint.

Comment: In this case I have the primary key also.. so...

Comment: @WSS . . . The declaration of `PRIMARY KEY` already creates an index.  There is no need to create an index on the same columns.  (Well, actually, there might be some rare cases when you have a composite key and you want an index in a different order, but in general, one index on a set of columns is sufficient.)